# How much max distance of SPI & USB & I2C and TWI(without any IC

Tags: usb, spi, i2c, protocol, twi

How much max distance of SPI & USB & I2C and TWI(without any IC(my mean is directly)), and how can i amplify these?

Comment: This question shows a lack of research on the subject: did you try to look at protocol specifications?

Answer (score 2):

USB is required to work up to 5 meters and will become unreliable beyond that.

The other communication standards you mention are much vaguer about their requirements. For SPI and I2C it depends very much on speed; 100kHZ may work for tens of meters, 1MHz may not work well beyond one meter. It also depends on having a shielded cable with correct termination. See e.g. [SPI Bus Termination Considerations](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33372/spi-bus-termination-considerations?rq=1) , [SPI or I2C: which to use for a longish bus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/spi-or-i2c-which-to-use-for-a-longish-bus?rq=1) (which also mentions repeaters). Both of those suggest looking at CAN and RS485.

I don't know what you mean by "(without any IC(my mean is directly))" given that it's always between two ICs?

Comment: Well, my mean without rs232 and etc

Comment: why changing it by changing frequency?

Comment: Generally a long cable will "smear" a sharp rising or falling signal edge into more of a blur. At high frequency the pulses are shorter and more easily corrupted. Also, it takes time for a signal to propagate and the answer to return.